# JUnit 5 @ParamterizedTest {arguments} vs {argumentsWithNames} placeholders

Tags: java, junit5, parametrized-testing

I'm using JUnit 5.7.0, IntellijIDEA 2021.1.2 CE, MacOS Catalina 10.15. and don't understand the difference between
`ParameterizedTest.ARGUMENTS_PLACEHOLDER` and `ParameterizedTest.ARGUMENTS_WITH_NAMES_PLACEHOLDER`.

According to the javadoc `ARGUMENTS_WITH_NAMES_PLACEHOLDER` deals with named arguments whereas `ARGUMENTS_PLACEHOLDER` with just arguments.
The test result in IDEA for both tests looks the same:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;

@ParameterizedTest(name = ARGUMENTS_WITH_NAMES_PLACEHOLDER)
@CsvSource({"apple, 1", "banana, 2", "'lemon, lime', 3" })
void testWithArguments(String fruit, int rank) {
}

@ParameterizedTest(name = ARGUMENTS_PLACEHOLDER)
@CsvSource({"apple, 1", "banana, 2", "'lemon, lime', 3" })
void testWithNamedArguments(String fruit, int rank) {
}
```

[image]

Can anyone provide an example where these two placeholders behave differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

For `ARGUMENTS_WITH_NAMES_PLACEHOLDER` to work as expected, tests must be compiled with
`-parameters` flag. Then, argument names will be 1) stored, and 2) be able to be subsequently retrieved by JUnit via reflection.

### In Practice

For Java projects built with Gradle, the following would enable this flag specifically for tests:

```
tasks.named('compileTestJava') {
    options.compilerArgs += '-parameters'
}
```

## Reference

- From [Java 8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) on `javac`:

  > `-parameters`  Stores formal parameter names of constructors and methods in the generated class file so that the method `java.lang.reflect.Executable.getParameters` from the Reflection API can retrieve them.
- Naturally, JUnit is using reflection to get parameter names. For instance, check out [`ParameterizedTestMethodContext#getParameterName`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/r5.7.1/junit-jupiter-params/src/main/java/org/junit/jupiter/params/ParameterizedTestMethodContext.java#L119) (example from v5.7.1).

Answer (score 1):

If you use `@ParameterizedTest(name = ARGUMENTS_WITH_NAMES_PLACEHOLDER)` you'll get output result with `parameterName` + "=" + `paraveterValue`.

But if you use `@ParameterizedTest(name = ARGUMENTS_PLACEHOLDER)` you'll get only `paraveterValue`

Also, you can see that in javadoc:

```
Placeholder for the complete, comma-separated named arguments list of the current invocation of a @ParameterizedTest method: {argumentsWithNames}

@API(status = EXPERIMENTAL, since = "5.6")
String ARGUMENTS_WITH_NAMES_PLACEHOLDER = "{argumentsWithNames}";

Default display name pattern for the current invocation of a @ParameterizedTest method: "[{index}] {argumentsWithNames}"
Note that the default pattern does not include the display name of the @ParameterizedTest method.

@API(status = EXPERIMENTAL, since = "5.3")
String DEFAULT_DISPLAY_NAME = "[" + INDEX_PLACEHOLDER + "] " + ARGUMENTS_WITH_NAMES_PLACEHOLDER;
```

I tried to run your code like that:

```
@ParameterizedTest(name = ARGUMENTS_WITH_NAMES_PLACEHOLDER)
@CsvSource({"apple, 1", "banana, 2", "'lemon, lime', 3" })
void testWithNamedArguments(String fruit, int rank) {
}
```

and I got the correct result:

[image]

I use jupiter 5.6.3, the feature ARGUMENTS_WITH_NAMES_PLACEHOLDER appeared since 5.6 version.

Comment: So then why is the test result for {argumentsWithNames} not "fruit = apple , rank = 1" etc., but just "apple, 1" . Or prolly parameterName should be specified separately somehow via additional annotations ?

Comment: I see the same result as OP originally, but after maven reload project in IDEA, I see the result as answer.

Comment: OP can you try to execute maven goal mvn clean -am and then try to run with ARGUMENTS_WITH_NAMES_PLACEHOLDER parameter, maybe your test uses the oldest compile data

Comment: I'm using Gradle. I've rebuilt test, but nothing changed. I thought that there is an issue on IDEA side because in official tutorial video test's output doesn't have parameter's name as well: https://youtu.be/we3zJE3hlWE?t=879 . On top of that I've tried to run tests via ConsoleLauncher: ` java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.7.2.jar -cp ./build/classes/java/test --scan-classpath` and output also doesn't have names.
So it seems I had to ask another question: smth like: why {argumentsWithNames} placeholder doesn't work.

Comment: @DmitriiB Can I fix the `paraveterValue`? I just can't sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the `-parameter` option, if you stand still with Apache Maven,

```xml
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <parameters>true</parameters>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```